# Using overloaded/replaced delete[] on nullptr

Tags: c++

After searching on stackoverflow I've found that: "It's still the responisiblity of operator delete (or delete[]) to check; the standard doesn't guarantee that it won't be given a null pointer; the standard requires that it be a no-op if given a null pointer. "([delete a NULL pointer does not call overloaded delete when destructor is written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108360/delete-a-null-pointer-does-not-call-overloaded-delete-when-destructor-is-written))
Now to my question, is there any way to force the compiler to generate code that actually calls the overloaded/replaced delete[](for nullptr), example:

```
void *operator new[] (size_t n)
{
     std::cout << "new works ";
    return std::malloc (n);
}

void operator delete [] ( void* ptr) {
     if(!ptr) {
          std::cout << "you just tried to delete a nullptr";
          return;
     }
     else {
          std::cout << "delete works";
          free(ptr);
     }
}
int main(){

     char *p(new char[5]);
     char *q = nullptr;
     delete[] p;
     delete[] q;
     return 0;
}
```

Like this it produces the output:

```
new works delete works
```

I've tried compiling it with -O0, but that doesn't seem to change anything(additional info: g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
)

Comment: Yes, you should be able override global `new` / `delete`. `delete` operator accepts `nullptr` to be compatible with usual `free` semantics. It is not clear why do you want to check it for passed nullptr though.

Comment: @VTT and how do I do that?

Comment: The snippet you posted should work.

Comment: It doesn't, try it yourself.

Comment: Maybe your compiler is optimizing out the last `delete`?

Comment: Deleting a null pointer is defined to be a no-op, so it is possible that the compiler saw that q is always null and removed the call.

Comment: It works fine in debug build, even delete with nullptr.

Comment: Tried, works: http://rextester.com/RZA51383

Comment: It doesn't get called even in a more complex program for me(where the pointers aren't nullptr the whole time), and fine @Revolver_Ocelot it works there, doesn't work for me, but still doesn't answer my question if I can somehow force it to get called always. https://ideone.com/WRwInL

Comment: In your linked question there is an answer pointing that compiler is allowed to call deallocation function with null pointer, but standard does not requires it. So, there is no standard compliant way to force specific behavior. You must check your compiler documentation to see if it provides a way to do that (probably not). The last resort would be to change compiler itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard leaves this behaviour unspecified.

C++11, §5.3.5, item 7:

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null
>   pointer value, the delete-expression will call a deallocation function
>   (3.7.4.2). Otherwise, it is unspecified whether the deallocation
>   function will be called.

C++14 adds some details for the case of a non-null pointer, but the null case is the same.

If there is any way to force any specific behaviour, it would be a compiler extension.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but fine.